# How to convert HashSet to byte[]?

Tags: java

I have requirement where i want to store Hash Set i have to byte[] in database. I have searched through internet haven't found a solution.

I have following hashset of custom class.

```
HashSet<MyClass> set = new HashSet<MyClass>();
```

Please help.

Comment: Just serialize it. Google "java serialize object".

Answer (score 1):

You can serialize it, if the stored data is serializable.  Then convert to bytes.